# VS Code Extension Command Icons Not Working

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am making a VS Code extension and need a run icon in the top bar (I have no idea what it is called but see the screenshot to see an example)

This is what I have defined in package.json

```json
{
    ...    
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            ...
            {
                "command": "<COMMAND>",
                "title": "Build and Run FTC App",
                "icon": "`$(debug-start)`"
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

I can run the command fine in command palette but the icon doesn't show up. This is an example of an [extension (the green play button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdcSR.png) that does it (Source: Official Python Extension).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the command in two places in the `package.json`.

```json
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "<COMMAND>",
            "icon": "$(play)",
            "title": "Build and Run FTC App"
        }
    ],
    "menus": {
        "editor/title/run": [
            {
                "command": "<COMMAND>",
                "group": "navigation@0",
                "title": "Build and Run FTC App"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

First, register the command in the `commands` part.
It adds this command to the command palette.
This section is the place you also write down what is the icon of the command.

In addition, you need to add the command to the `editor/title/run` menu under the `menus` section.